# how customize django graphql-jwt

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, graphql, daphne

how customize backend authenticate for graphql-jwt? If i user BaseBackend and return user i get exception
"  graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_anonymous' "

```
class MyBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, *profile):
        user = User()
        user.social_id = int(profile.get('user_id'))
        user.expires_at = profile.get('expires_at')
        user.last_verification_code = "{:04}".format(random.randrange(1, 10**4))
        user.set_unusable_password()
        user.save()
        token = get_token(user)
        authenticate(username=user.full_name, password=user.password)
        login(request, user, backend='graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend')
        return user
```